# Retrieve access from Request Connector in Mule Anypoint Studio

Tags: http, oauth, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to store the access token value from request connector separately in variable.
can some one help on it.
using Oauth module 1.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<oauth:retrieve-access-token>` operation to get the token from the the [token manager](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-authentication#token-manager-configuration).

Example:

```
<oauth:retrieve-access-token tokenManager="tokenManagerConfig" target="accessToken"/>
```

I recommend to upgrade the module to the [latest version available to get bug fixes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/oauth-module-release-notes). 1.1.0 is an old version by now.

Comment: Message               : null

Element DSL           : <oauth:retrieve-access-token doc:name="Retrieve access token" doc:id="a6008e48-1a2b-4801-a4be-ca29ac5db5ae" target="accessToken" targetValue="#[payload.accessToken]">
<oauth:token-manager objectStore="Object_store"></oauth:token-manager>
</oauth:retrieve-access-token>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN

Comment: is we need to use object store ?

Comment: how we connect this <oauth:retrieve-access-token connector  to recieved token in request connector

Comment: Check the link I added for the token manager documentation.

Comment: yup works. thanks tokken retrieved but s too long doesnt look like a real token value , anyway thanks for yoour time